# Calculate angle between two lines

Tags: geometry

We have four points: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. We only know length of line `cd` and line `ab`. We also know that points `c` and `d` have same `x` coordinate, also points `a` and `b` have same `x` coordinate. Lines `cd` and `ab` are parallel. How can I find angle (marked as green) between lines `ca` and line `db`? Please provide example of calculations.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Also, if we _only_ know the two orange segment lengths ($cd$ and $ab$), then the angle can be pretty much anything. We need to know something more. The length of the two black segments (that is, $ac$ and $bd$) would help, but even that is not entirely enough.

Comment: The angle between the line segment $\text{CA}$ and $\text{DB}$ is clearly $?^{\circ}.$

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for clarification. Will it be possible to calculate, if we will also know that points `c` and `d` have same `y` coordinate, also points `a` and `b` have same `y` coordinate?

Comment: No, same $y$ doesn't suffice, if $x$-es differ much the angle can be arbitrarily small. (BTW, you didn't say what the $Y$ direction is.)

Comment: I guess he meant "the same x-coordinate" - at least, according to the image and the usual conventions about x and y

Comment: @CiaPan  Sorry. I mean same is `x`, noy `y`. Question corrected.

Comment: @Marco13 You are right. Thank you for correction.

Comment: The problem as it is right now still has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Tunococ Please provide any of solution with any example with actual calculations.

Comment: @vasili111 From your drawing, you can *slide* CD and AB in any direction while keeping the vertical orientation of both segments. The angle will vary as you slide them around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the points with their coordinates $a_x, a_y ... d_x, d_y$, you can compute the angle of each line to the x-axis (using the [arcustangens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function), and then just compute the difference between these angles.

So you can compute the angles

$\alpha_0 = atan2(c_y-a_y, c_x-a_x)$

and

$\alpha_1 = atan2(d_y-b_y, d_x-b_x)$

(see the wikipedia link for the definition of the $atan2$ function).

The angle between the lines is then simply $\alpha_1-\alpha_0$

---

EDIT: The example:

- $a_x = 100$, $a_y = 5$
- $b_x = 100$, $b_y = 0$
- $c_x = 0$, $c_y = 8$
- $d_x = 0$, $d_y = 0$

Now compute

$\alpha_0 = atan2(c_y-a_y, c_x-a_x) = atan2(3, -100)$
$\alpha_1 = atan2(d_y-b_y, d_x-b_x) = atan2(0, -100)$

According to the cases described in this image from wikipedia:

[image]

We have

$\alpha_0 = atan(3/-100) + \pi \approx 3.1116016487329152$

$\alpha_1 = atan(0/-100) + \pi \approx 3.141592653589793$

And the angle is then the difference

$\alpha = \alpha_1 - \alpha_0 \approx 0.02999100485687789 \approx 1.718°$

Comment: I agree that simply writing in TeX would make it more relevant.

Comment: @Marco13 Can you please provide the example of step by step calculations? For example: length of ab=5, length of cd=8.

Comment: @vasili111 The lengths are not enough. Provide the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of all four points.

Comment: @Marco13 This seems much more succinct and to the point. But I guess the OP will keep asking for calculation...

Comment: @Marco13 Point `b` x=100, y=0; Point `a` x=100, y=5; Point `d` x=0, y=0; Point `c` x=0, y=8.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two lines given by vector equations, say $\bf{p}+\lambda{\bf u}$ and ${\bf q}+\mu{\bf v}$, and the accute angle between the lines is $\theta$ then there is a well-known relationship:

$$\cos\theta = \left| \frac{{\bf u} \cdot {\bf v}}{\|{\bf u}\|\,\|{\bf v}\|} \right|$$

Notice that only the directions ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ of the two lines are needed.

If a line passes through points ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf c}$ then the line has direction ${\bf c}-{\bf a}$ because ${\bf c}-{\bf a}$ is the vector from  ${\bf a}$ to ${\bf c}$. If you know all of the coordinates of the points then you can work out the direction vectors of the two lines and then apply the formula to get $\cos\theta$. Then use $\cos^{-1}$ to get $\theta$.

Comment: Please provide any example with actual calculations.

Comment: @vasili111 No. We are not here to do your homework for you. I have given you all the tools you need. Now it's your turn.

Answer (score 2):

we make a line parellel to the line $bd$, showed in this picture:[image]

then the angle you want is equal to the angle $\angle cad'$, and $dd'=ab$, because $ab\parallel cd$.
so $cd'=cd-ab$.

now we can calculate the angle $\angle cad'$ in the triangle $\bigtriangleup cad'$.
$$\cos(\angle cad')=\frac{ac^2+bd^2-d'c^2}{2\cdot ac\cdot bd}$$
then you have the angle by the function $\arccos()$.

In fact your inital conditions are not enough. from the two following pictures, we know that:[image][image]

1) when we only know the length of $ab$ and $cd$, the angle between $ac$ and $bd$ depends the distance between $ab$ and $cd$;

2) though $ab$ and $cd$ has a certain distance $\Delta x$, the angle between $ac$ and $bd$ depends also the hight of $ab$.

Comment: Can you please provide example of calculations?

Comment: $\tan \angle cad' = \frac {cd'}{ad'} = \frac {cd'}{bd}$, so $\angle cad' = \arctan \frac {cd'}{bd}$

Comment: I think the calculation is very clear, and don't understand what kind of example you need. Perhaps you give all the initial numeric conditions, then I show you the calculations.

Comment: @CiaPan we are not sure that the triangle is a right triangle, so I don't think we can use the function $\tan$.

Comment: @Martial For example: length of ab=5, length of cd=8 . Can you please provide step by step calculations with that numeric conditions?

Comment: @Martial You're right, the image suggested a right angle but the description does not contain such condition. Sorry for that. Shall I delete my comment? Is there any way to mark it as wrong (but not remove to keep the comments chain consistent)?

Comment: @vasili111 I edit my answer, hope it helps you

Comment: @Martial Thank you for clarification. I understand now why my question is wrong. What if we add to my question that points `d` and `b` have both coordinate y=0 ?

Comment: @vasili111 I think you need also suppose that $x_d=0$, $x_b=x$, then this problem could be solved

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly: cd and ab are parallel. So you can shrink your problem to a triangle. Where your requested angle (let's call him $\alpha$) depends on the angles of $cdb$ (here $\beta$) and $dca$ (here $\gamma$) or any other two angles in your figure.

Thus all these three angles must be $180° = \alpha + \beta + \gamma$ in the sum.

So I think your problem is under determined.

Comment: Yes, lins `cd` and `ab` are parallel. Can you please provide any example of calculations?

Comment: I thought about the same Martial did.